Problem with streamlit text_input and display result
I'm trying to create a chatbot-like app using Streamlit, and I'm facing some issues with the text_input and how to display that. To be more specific, when I click the button "Edit Chat Name" on it appears correctly the text_input field and I enter the text but instead of being displayed with the new name, the value displays as empty.
from openai import OpenAI
import streamlit as st
import uuid


if "chat_sessions" not in st.session_state:
    st.session_state.chat_sessions = {}  # Dictionary to store multiple chat sessions
    st.session_state.current_chat_id = None  # ID of the currently selected chat
    st.session_state.chat_names = {}  # Dictionary to store chat names


def start_new_chat():
    new_chat_id = str(uuid.uuid4())  # Generate a unique ID for the new chat
    st.session_state.chat_sessions[new_chat_id] = []  # Create a new empty chat
    st.session_state.current_chat_id = new_chat_id  # Set as the current chat
    st.session_state.chat_names[new_chat_id] = "Chat"  # Set a default name for the chat


def select_chat(chat_id):
    st.session_state.current_chat_id = chat_id


def remove_chat():
    if st.session_state.current_chat_id in st.session_state.chat_sessions:
        del st.session_state.chat_sessions[st.session_state.current_chat_id]
        del st.session_state.chat_names[st.session_state.current_chat_id]
        st.session_state.current_chat_id = None  # Reset current chat ID

        # If there are remaining chat sessions, select the first one
        if st.session_state.chat_sessions:
            st.session_state.current_chat_id = list(st.session_state.chat_sessions.keys())[0]


def edit_chat_name():
    if st.session_state.current_chat_id:
        st.session_state.chat_names[st.session_state.current_chat_id] = st.sidebar.text_input("New chat name")


def clear_chat_history():
    st.session_state.chat_sessions[st.session_state.current_chat_id] = []


# Sidebar layout
with st.sidebar:
    st.title(' AI Chatbot')
    st.button('New Chat', on_click=start_new_chat)  # Add New Chat button

    # List previous chats and allow the user to select them
    if st.session_state.chat_sessions:
        selected_chat = st.radio(
            "Select a chat",
            options=list(st.session_state.chat_sessions.keys()),
            format_func=lambda x: st.session_state.chat_names.get(x, f"Chat {x[:8]}")
        )
        select_chat(selected_chat)

    st.button('Edit Chat Name', on_click=edit_chat_name)
    st.button('Remove Chat', on_click=remove_chat)
    st.button('Clear Chat History', on_click=clear_chat_history)

st.title("Chat")

# Point to the local server
client = OpenAI(base_url="http://localhost:1234/v1", api_key="not-needed")

if "openai_model" not in st.session_state:
    st.session_state["openai_model"] = "local-model"

# Ensure a chat session is selected
if st.session_state.current_chat_id is None:
    start_new_chat()

# Get the messages for the current chat session
current_chat = st.session_state.chat_sessions[st.session_state.current_chat_id]

# Display chat messages from history
for message in current_chat:
    with st.chat_message(message["role"]):
        st.markdown(message["content"])

# Handle user input
if prompt := st.chat_input("Enter prompt"):
    current_chat.append({"role": "user", "content": prompt})
    with st.chat_message("user"):
        st.markdown(prompt)

    # Generate AI response
    with st.chat_message("assistant"):
        stream = client.chat.completions.create(
            model=st.session_state["openai_model"],
            messages=[{"role": m["role"], "content": m["content"]} for m in current_chat],
            temperature=0.7,
            stream=True,
        )
        response = st.write_stream(stream)
    current_chat.append({"role": "assistant", "content": response})

# Note: The line below is not part of the Streamlit app execution
# You run the Streamlit app with the following command:
# python -m streamlit run Streamlit.py

When I passed "Greetings" directly in the code like this:
def edit_chat_name():
    if st.session_state.current_chat_id:
        st.session_state.chat_names[st.session_state.current_chat_id] = "Greetings"

It worked nicely. I expected it to work nicely too when I entered the name using text_input() method, but it displays nothing instead.
Before click "Edit Chat Name"
When entering new chat name
After new chat name entered

Define st.sidebar.text_input("New chat name") when you are building the sidebar with st.sidebar. Then hold the value of it in a session variable. Use that variable inside edit_chat_name
